# MySQL Query Performance (InnoDB)

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have a `InnoDB` table with ~50MB (~500.000 entries).

*Table Structure:* <kbd>id</kbd><kbd>user_id</kbd><kbd>info</kbd>

---

*Querys:*

I would like to get the next entry of this user that has the ID higher than 10:

`` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `id` > 10 LIMIT 1 ``
 (Response: ~0.5ms)

I would like to get the next entry of this user that has the ID higher than 300000:

`` SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `id` > 300000 LIMIT 1 ``
 (Response: **~215ms**)

---

I tried several index, but no one decreased the response time:

`ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (user_id, id);`

How can I improve the performance in this case?

Comment: Can you share an `explain` on both queries?

Comment: Just to be sure; how is the response time being measured, how many rows are being returned, and is `info` a blob containing a large amount of data?

Comment: @RC question updated.

Comment: Also, those queries have no guarantee of getting you the "next entry higher than X" without using an `order by` clause.

Comment: @Uueerdo directly using Sequel. Info a field text and it's not large data.

Comment: I meant explain as in https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html not some kind of explanation :p

Comment: why the index is on table `line` and the select is `FROM 'table'`?

Comment: @Uueerdo it's ordered by id ASC by default.

Comment: If you have the "user_id, id" index , can you try  "SELECT user_id,id FROM `table` WHERE `user_id`=1 AND `id` > 300000 LIMIT 1" and share the execution time

Comment: "directly" as in workbench, query browser, command line? Tables have no default ordering. And also, to make sure, `id` and `user_id` are integers?

Comment: Read about the importance of the order of the columns in the view http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that `id` is your `PRIMARY KEY`, you should create this index:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD INDEX (user_id);
```

and add an `ORDER BY` condition to your query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    `table`
WHERE   `user_id` = 1
        AND `id` > 300000
ORDER BY
        id
LIMIT   1
```

The index will be in fact on `(user_id, id)`, as the primary key columns missing in the index keys are implicitly a trailing part of every InnoDB secondary index.